# Altair LOESS Smoothing with Date

Tags: pandas, altair, loess

i liked making Plots with Altair lately, unfortunately Smoothing of Timeseries doesn't work that well.

So this is my base plot (the data doesn't really need smoothing, but let's ignore that)

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

temps = temps[temps.date < '2010-01-15']

alt.Chart(temps).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='temp:Q'
)
```

If i just use transform_loess on it, i get an empty plot:

```
alt.Chart(temps).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='temp:Q'
).transform_loess("date","temp",bandwidth=.3)
```

If i transform the Datetime Variable to Ordinal it works, but the x-axis is not correct anymore, i already tried some formatting, but with no success:

```
from datetime import datetime

temps['date_ordinal'] = temps['date'].apply(lambda date: datetime.timestamp(date))

alt.Chart(temps).mark_line().encode(
    x = alt.X('date_ordinal:T', axis = alt.Axis( format = ("%Y%b%d%H"))),
    y='temp:Q'
).transform_loess("date_ordinal","temp",bandwidth=.05)
```

I'm aware i could also just smooth the data beforehand, but my original dataset has many variables, so i would need to do it in a pandas groupby somehow.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar. This isn't much better than doing it outside of altair, but it will work ¯_(ツ)_/¯:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()
temps = data.seattle_temps()
temps["t"] = temps["date"].apply(
    lambda d: d.timestamp()
)

a = alt.Chart(temps).mark_line().encode(
    x='date',
    y='temp:Q'
)
b = alt.Chart(temps).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('t', title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, ticks=False),
            scale=alt.Scale(nice=False)),
    y='temp:Q',
)

a + b.transform_loess('t', 'temp').mark_line(size=4, color="red")
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26e5e.png)